# Can't install Ubuntu because pc keeps shutting down

Tags: ubuntu, partition, windows, system-installation, wubi

I can't install Ubuntu because during the "copying files" my PC powers off.

I've downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 with WUBI on my Windows 8.1 32-bit PC. I made a new partition with 15.9GB, (I don't know if I need more memory on my partition)
Then WUBI, correctly, reboots.
But then when it gets to "copying files", the computer powers off.

Before it shuts down, it looks like this.

[image: Copying files]

Comment: @kprovost7314 how it shutdown, does it restart correctly,  BSOD, AC off ?

Comment: please go here, I will help you to make the question clear, so some one will answer. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15866/cant-install-ubuntu-because-pc-keeps-shutting-down--clarification

Comment: I don't know an answer, but you could try downloading a live version of Ubuntu, and trying that. A live version runs from CD (or usb), it will not write to the harddisk. It is useful for testing the hardware (as well as other uses). Also 16GB is plenty to install Ubuntu, I have always used 20GB and after years of installing extra programs not gone past 16GB, am currently on 8.4GB

Comment: I have no CD's or USB sticks.

Comment: You may be able to do a network boot live, but you will need another computer for that, and a network cable.

Comment: @kprovost7314 I will try to remain polite but you did not answer mine either.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, It just shut down without BSOD and restart.

Comment: Hi @Kiwy, I have tryed to help kprovost7314 to amend the question to answer our question. Did we miss something? Also kprovost7314, I recommend tidying, remove first comment about copying files, what do you mean, and comment about no one answering. We want to remove anything that does not apply any more to make it easier to read.

Comment: I realized that my PC kept getting hot, so I got a fan and it worked.